# Cannot connect to laravel-websocket CORS issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-websockets

I deployed my laravel application in GCP.  I also set up SSL on my application https://myapp.com. It was working fine connecting to the pusher server.  Then I switched to laravel-web sockets.  I modified the same code in my `/var/www/myapp` with the following:

.env

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=sample_id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=sample_key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=samples_secret
```

config/broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: 127.0.0.1,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true
});
```

Then I run it with

```
php artisan Webockets:serve
```

Then I go to my app https://myapp.com and got these errors.  I am not able to connect to my WebSocket:

```
wss://myapp.com/app/sample_key?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.6&flash=false
Finished
```

And a series of

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://myapp.com/app/sample_key?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.6&flash=false' failed: 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sockjs-ap1.pusher.com/pusher/app/sample_key/856/8g5crt3n/xhr_streaming?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.6&t=1649947314189&n=1' from origin 'https://myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

POST https://sockjs-ap1.pusher.com/pusher/app/sample_key/856/8g5crt3n/xhr_streaming?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.6&t=1649947314189&n=1 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Do you have this `process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER` attribute in env file?

Comment: Follow this steps: https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher and if SSL is on then add this `forceTLS:true`

Comment: It looks like your code that runs in the websocket is making an Ajax request to sockjs-ap1.pusher.com. Do you have to do any configurations at sockjs-ap1.pusher.com to whitelist your hostname (https://myapp.com)?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're using Laravel Sail (Docker), you might check if you open your websocket port in `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
services:
    laravel.test:
        #...
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
            - '6001:6001' #websocket port added here
```

If it doesn't work, you can also remove the `cluster` option for Echo (not necessary for laravel-websockets) and add a `wss` option with the same port.

```js
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install: pusher/pusher-php-server

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"
```

config/broadcasting.php:

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'http'
        ],
    ],
```

app.js:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS:false,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

.env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```